# Trying to upload image using AndroidAsyncHttp not working

Tags: java, android

We are trying to upload an image along with other strings using `AsyncHttpClient` library.The following is what we have done till now:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                        params.put("userId", user_id);
                        params.put("proofDocId", idproofno);
                        params.put("proofFilename",proofFilename);
                        params.put("docType", docType);
                        try {
                            params.put("proof",new File(img_path));
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                      client.post(Constants.UPLOAD_URL,params,new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
                          @Override
                          public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                              super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                              if(progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                  progressDialog.dismiss();
                              }
                              String status = response.toString();
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                              super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
                          }
                      });
```

The `img_path` string is the location of the image on the device.The JSON response is returned in such a manner indicating that the image was not found.But we tried the same Web Service on POSTMAN rest client on chrome and file upload works fine.Why is the image/file not uploading?Please Help.

Comment: you just check   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149315/cant-upload-image-to-server-using-asynchttpclient-in-android

Comment: please test with hardcoding image path like     String imagePath="file://sdcard/Images/tempge.jpg";

Comment: Show the script that is receiving the POST.

Comment: @saeed i tried hard coding the path.It is still not working.

Comment: @greenapps I cannot get you the script code since it belongs to a client.But the web service is working fine on POSTMAN rest client.

Comment: You have no catch block. If there is a catch you should display a toast saying so and return there. Do not continue with your code if there is a catch.